# How is one supposed to use the F# SqlDataConnection TypeProvider with an App.Config file?

Tags: f#, app-config

I am using the type expression:

```
type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<ConnectionStringName="X1", ConfigFile="App.config">
```

This works great at compile time (I have full access to all the db types), but it fails at run time. I presume it's because the config file generated in the console application's `bin` directory is named something else, such as `MyAppName.exe.config`, and therefore the `App.config` file is not found.

Certainly, for an *ASP.NET MVC* type app that uses `web.config`, there's no issue because the compile and runtime config filenames are the same.

Fortunately, placing a duplicate `App.config` in the `bin` directory does remediate the problem, but is that what we are expected to do? Any thoughts?

Comment: This is the way how `App.config` works. It is first being looked for a top-level calling assembly. See [this Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569336/visual-c-sharp-app-config-file-for-a-referenced-assembly) for details. Also notice that `App.config` is actually renamed to `MyAppName.exe.config` during build time, and you may need proper calling your newly created one.

Comment: @bytebuster That's certainly true. However the SqlDataConnection type provider doesn't seem to be aware of this fact and still insists on the file "app.config" to be there, even if `ConfigFile` is not specified explicitly (in which case app.config should be used as the default.)

Comment: I've been thinking about this myself. Maybe you'll find this question and answer helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19459561/952606

Answer (score 1):

The description of how the type provider definition works is misleading - the value in the typedef really only matters at code/compile time, and as a default at runtime. However, as you've noted, it isn't very smart about finding the correct config file at runtime.

You can accomplish what you want by passing the connection string as a parameter to GetDataContext:

```
type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<ConnectionStringName="X2">
let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.["X2"].ConnectionString)
```

...or if you also want to make it work in F# interactive, wrap it like so:

```
type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<ConnectionStringName="X2">
#if COMPILED
let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.["X2"].ConnectionString)
#else
let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
#endif
```

(Note that you will need a reference to System.Configuration.)

Comment: This is roughly the same answer that was linked by spacedoom above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a VS2012 on this PC but this should be what you're looking for :

```
let exeConfigFile = Path.GetFileName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + ".config"
let defaultConfigFile = "App.config"
let configFile = if File.Exists(exeConfigFile) then exeConfigFile else defaultConfigFile

type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<ConnectionStringName="X1", ConfigFile=configFile>
```

Comment: No luck!  Compiler says for `configfile`: "This is not a constant expression or valid custom attribute value.